# Applying CSS transform scale and rotate simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I have a page that has an image that can be zoomed and rotated. See an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/viniciuspaiva/38AzW/

I used CSS transform to that, but the button that rotates is different than the button that applies the zoom, so I needed the CSS to, somehow, save the previously state (zooming a rotated image, for example).

I tried a "brute-force" approach, creating a data-state (0, 1, 2 or 3) attribute that controls the rotation and a class "zoom" that applies the zoom. But when I zoom, I can't maintain the rotation.

I tried also creating a lot of CSS to prevent all the cases, example below, but didn't work.

```
.zoom [data-state='0']{  
transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(1.3) rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}

[data-state='0']{  
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: looks like you use inline-script, so why not just use script normally? a pure CSS solution may require you to use some elements that can memorize states such as checkbox, radio button.

Comment: next times please tag it correctly. Also avoid using inline-script, it's just a mess (not a pro style)

Comment: Why are you not using JS?  This would be easier to handle data/states with JS and just use CSS for the actual animation.

Comment: @Ennui actually he used JS here, but it's inline-script. It should be avoided. Otherwise I think it's not easy (but doesn't mean impossible) to find some pure CSS solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a syntax error on your side, there shouldn't be spaces :

```
.zoom[data-state='1']{  
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)  scale(1.3); 
}

.zoom[data-state='2']{  
  transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg)  scale(1.3); 
}
.zoom[data-state='3']{  
  transform: rotate(270deg) scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)  scale(1.3); 
}
```

The selector that you used

```
.zoom [data-state='1'] {}
```

refers to a data-state element that is a *child* of a zoom element

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38AzW/2/)

Comment: have you checked out the fiddle? the code there is different. Also have you checked if it actually works with this change? The hard-to-understand thing here is the OP uses inline-script, that means script is needed here, so we can just put all the script at a place and this problem is just a trivia if we use script.

Comment: @KingKing The inline scripting is used to add the zoom class, and the data-state values. And those are referenced in the CSS. Added fiddle with that solution. Of course, you can go fully the inline style way, but I was following the direction that the OP had choose. He was only an space away from the solution :-)

Comment: I understand why the script is needed, but because of its inline-style, I did not even care to look into them, so terrible to write script like that. That's why I asked for the OP why inline script? If he put all the script at some place, it would be like that he wants some ***script*** solution. However he did not even tag his question with scripting like jQuery or javascript. So I doubt that he might want some pure CSS solution, (he might consider his code to look like no-script code, but actually it needs script to run).

Comment: @KingKing I absolute agree that inline scripting is **terrible**

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Bad, bad space. And the reason for inline scripting is that it is a solution still in progress, I made that just to see if attended. Now I'm gonna refactor it! =)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/38AzW/1/

I only added the following to your class `center`

css:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
```

Comment: no, the OP does not want transition (or at least he knows this if he wants), he wants some combination of rotate and scale but each button has its own functionality, one for rotate and one for scale, scaling should not ***clear/reset*** rotating and vice-versa.